# Swift inline closure bug?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, closures

I'm learning Swift through the book provided by Apple. In the closures section, I noticed these three ways of adding a closure to the sort method produce different numbers of iterations to sort the array.

```
let names = ["chris", "alex", "eva", "barry", "daniella"]

let reverse1 = names.sort({ (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in
    return s1 > s2
})

let reverse2 = names.sort( { (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in return s1 > s2 })

let reverse3 = names.sort({ s1, s2 in s1 > s2 })
```

[image: xcode]

Is this a bug? Because the only thing different for `reverse1` and `reverse2` is a line break.

Comment: It is not a bug. The numbers (6 times), (10 times) etc. has different meaning from what you expect. See Apple docs. There is also a talk with explanation on stackoverflow ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure is executed 9 times in every scenario, the 10th is the printing of `reverse1`, `reverse2` etc... If you are using the same closures, but not inlined, it will print exactly the same as in the first case:
[image]

So it'a rather like how many times a line is executed, if you take a look at just a simple one line declaration separated by `;`:

[image]